# cannot load SignalR hub script in Autofac

Tags: asp.net, signalr, autofac

I'm trying to use SignalR with Autofac dependency in my application, i have successfully registered dependencies but on run time it is causing error that SignalR dyanmic generated file hubs is missing and without that i can't do anything. I've searched internet but couldn't find any solution. Please help.

Config Class:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(IocConfig), "RegisterDependencies")]

namespace Rental.Bootstrapper
{
    public class IocConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterDependencies()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            const string nameOrConnectionString = "name=DefaultConnection";
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(WebApiConfig).Assembly);
            builder.RegisterHubs(typeof(RentalHub).Assembly);
            //builder.RegisterInstance(typeof(Startup));
            builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerHttpRequest();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Service<>)).As(typeof(IService<>)).InstancePerHttpRequest();
            builder.RegisterType(typeof(UnitOfWork)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork)).InstancePerHttpRequest();
            builder.Register<IEntitiesContext>(b =>
            {
                var logger = b.Resolve<ILogger>();
                var context = new RentalContext(nameOrConnectionString, logger);
                return context;
            }).InstancePerHttpRequest();
            builder.Register(b => NLogLogger.Instance).SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterModule(new IdentityModule());

            var container = builder.Build();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
                 new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

            var signalRDependencyResolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = signalRDependencyResolver;                                  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the error message (with stack trace) and things you tried ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Application is running but i cannot use SignalR. There is no stack trace as such or server related errors, the only error error i can see on console is 404 for http://localhost:1370/signalr/hubs this link

Comment: @CyrilDurand How Autofac deal with SignalR scripts? i mean in a simple SignalR application we use owin startup type class which will generate automatic hubs scripts on DOM, how we can do this in Autofac?

Comment: Do you have a startup.cs file with OwinStartupAttribute on a namespace?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev No, I'm using dependency injection, do i need to add extra startup class in my UI? UI is depending on Dependency Layer.

Comment: You have to initialize SignalR as Owin middleware. Do you use Autofac integration with Owin for middleware injection? I do not see this from your container initialization code.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I'm new to autofac, can u please guide me how i can do this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Autofac. Check my answer below.

Comment: This question's code looks astoundingly similar to the code in the two previous questions you've asked (which still need to be combined into one question or closed).

Comment: @TravisIllig why don't u provide solution instead of finding human errors? Please don't waste time, give some solution. I've also posted on github.. How i make this working, when i have everything referenced in IOC layer (Autofac). how i can initialize signalr scripts?

Comment: When you follow the question asking tips that I and others have provided you are more likely to get help. People do this for free out of the goodness of their hearts. You can help us to better assist you if you get all the info we need in one place; or if questions aren't relevant anymore, close them so we don't waste time.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is not Autofac issue at all. I also assume that you use MVC4, which is using Owin by default. Owin has a startup class, where all middleware and extensions must be registered. Normally, this is a Startup.cs class that at its minimum, required for SignalR, contains this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MyNamepace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors = true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If you look at the MapSignalR method, you will find that it registers the"/signalr" route and this is exactly what you are missing, if I understand your question correctly:

```
/// <summary>
/// Maps SignalR hubs to the app builder pipeline at "/signalr".
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="builder">The app builder</param><param name="configuration">The <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration"/> to use</param>
public static IAppBuilder MapSignalR(this IAppBuilder builder, HubConfiguration configuration)
{
  return OwinExtensions.MapSignalR(builder, "/signalr", configuration);
}
```

**Autofac SignalR documentation** [has a section about Owin startup](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/signalr.html#owin-integration), I strongly suggest you look there. It has a complete code for the startup.cs file that includes Autofac container initialization, all registrations and Owin-related code for SignalR.

Comment: Where i need modifications? if i add startup class in UI layer then Autofac won't register that, i tried this method as well, the thing is signalR scripts are not being initialized in IOC (Autofac) layer.

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing what are you trying to do. Are you doing web application or not? Do you have Owin dependency? If not, my answer is irrelevant.

Comment: This is the server code, what I wrote. May be you need to read more about SignalR server instantiation? Have you checked the documentation link that I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I'm doing web application using a structure where i have only UI has Core Layer reference and IOC Layer have all references including core and UI, i successfully registered signalR in Autofac but when i try to use it in my Web Page (MVC) javascript popup an error "missing signalr/hubs" without this dynamic script i don't think so i can use signalr,

Comment: Check documentation, use the link I provided. I tried to explain as much as could. Your signalr route does not exist because sirnalr middleware is not registered with Owin. I am already repeating myself. You can just add the startup.cs file with the content I provided to the root of your web project and it should work.

Comment: Thanks sir, i will try now and update u with status.